# Not implicit waiting for new element after clicking

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm just wondering if there is a more reliable method for waiting for elements or if it's just a stubborn page.  I'm fairly new to Python Selenium but I notice without the Sleep wait below https://casino.bovada.lv/ (it's greyed out for now) command Selenium clicks the Poker Tab, then it before the page is properly loaded it clicks the horse's tab and this click does nothing.  I can use a sleep wait command but kind of defeats the purpose of having a wait for the element to appear.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Brother\chromedriver.exe')
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://sports.bovada.lv/soccer")

time.sleep( 4 )

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20000).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ui-app-primary-menu > a.primary-menu_item.channel-poker.channel.channel-poker.ng-isolate-scope > span")));

element.click();

driver.get("https://casino.bovada.lv/")
#time.sleep( 4 )
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20000).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ui-app-primary-menu > a.primary-menu_item.channel-horses.channel.channel-horses > span")));
element.click();
time.sleep( 15 )
###
driver.close()
```

I also tried

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 2222).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ui-app-primary-menu > a.primary-menu_item.channel-poker.channel.channel-poker.ng-isolate-scope > span'))).click();

WebDriverWait(driver, 2222).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ui-app-primary-menu > a.primary-menu_item.channel-horses.channel.channel-horses > span'))).click();
```

Comment: Do you realize that `WebDriverWait(driver, 20000)` means wait for about 5,5 hours?

Comment: @Andersson  Yeah.  It should wait until it finds the element.  I put a large value as if I put like 1 second it would likely fail.

Comment: OK. But if element not found your script will hang for 5,5 hours!

Comment: @Andersson To be honest, I haven't really investigated exception handling as such. I suppose I will look into it after I find a different method of waiting for elements I guess.  Or maybe I'll just not be fussy as sleep wait works I guess.

Comment: This seems like an angular site. You would be better off using protractor.

Answer (score 0):

I would to show recursive waiting algorithm, which I like to use in similar cases:

```
startTime = Date()
def recursive_wait(By: by):
        timeout = 3000
        duration = 0
        try:
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
            wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by))
            wait.until(EC.element_t_be_clickable(by))
        except (TimeoutException, ElementNotVisibleException e):
            duration = startTime.compareTo(Date())
            if (timeout < duration):
                recursive_wait(by)
```

This wait for element for 3000 seconds, but check is element appears every 5 seconds. Also, you can wait for many elements in try block.